# Adding and Removing an active class

Tags: jquery

I know this should be simple and has been covered a million times already but I just can;t seem to get it to work.

It's your basic script that makes the last link you clicked in a list become the 'active' link my adding the 'active' class to it.

HTML

```
<ul id="projectsList">
            <li><a href="#" class="activeProject" id="portoftyne">Port of Tyne</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="eaga">Eaga</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="gong">Gong</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="nufc">NUFC</a></li>
        </ul>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#projectsList a').click(function(){
         $('.activeProject').removeClass('activeProject')
         $(this).addClass("activeProject");
    });
});
```

Should work, doesn't at all.

**EDIT** Nothing wrong with this code, it works fine. There was a section of code above it in the document that was preventing it from working.

Comment: It works fine. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/cFGyt/ You must have other javascript that may be failing.

Comment: How are you testing the result? Perhaps the bug is in your CSS file so you're not getting visual feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't see any problem there.

look: http://jsfiddle.net/JqMK8/

it is working.

the mistake must be somewhere else

Comment: Yeah, I missed a `;` on the code just before it. Spent an hour looking at the wrong part :(

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest using a variable to hold reference to activeProject. In case you have large pages this would save a lot on the processing as searching DOM can be expensive. It will also make it less prone to problems like the one you're having (selecting the wrong element).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var active = $('#projectsList a.activeProject');
        $('#projectsList a').click(function() {
            if(active) $(active).removeClass('activeProject');
            $(this).addClass("activeProject");
            active=this;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try being more specific with the selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#projectsList li a').click(function(){
         $('.activeProject').removeClass('activeProject')
         $(this).addClass("activeProject");
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. This code works for other people...

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. I thought being more general would help lol.

Comment: Well, the code looks correct. Could you post the entire page and JS file? Maybe check the CSS? There seems to be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I try it and it works, nothing wrong in your code :

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jowan/2HSqh/3/)

Comment: I have never seen the `salmon` color used before (nor did I know of its existence)!

Comment: i know it from the book (http://www.jr.com/new-riders-publishing/pe/NRP_0321574168/). you can declare color in CSS with name of that  color

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the ID #projectsList is changed by your output processor? Could happen in .NET or certain Java frameworks.

Try to assign the class .projectsList instead and see if it works.

I could also recommend the practice of Event delegation instead:

```
$('.projectsList').click(function(evt){
  if ( evt.target.nodeName == 'A' ) {
    var elm = $(evt.target);
    if ( elm.hasClass('activeProject') ) { return; }
    $('.activeProject').removeClass('activeProject');
    $(evt.target).addClass('activeProject');
  }
});
```

(Simplified and quick written)

**UPDATE**
Sam, I recommend JavaScript Lint if you haven't tried it. Using it [online](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) or in your editor(there is bundles and plugins for it) will let you easily spot errors and warnings in your JavaScript code.